# In Azure Data Factory, how to alter the name of the copied file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline. I have a copy activity which copies files from a Cosmos DB container to blob storage. I need to change the copied files name so that it is like the original file but has the date of copy prepended to it.

Comment: Could you share your attempt and what is the exact requirement in the approach?

Comment: I want to copy all files created in the last 24 hours from a Cosmos database to blob storage. All files should be prepended with the date (ddMMyyyy) they were copied. I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234522/in-azure-data-factory-how-to-alter-the-name-of-the-copied-file?noredirect=1#comment134437890_76234522

Comment: The link that is provided above is this page link

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the process should look like this:

1. Get Metadata Activity to get all files that have been modified between X and Y [image: Get Metadata]
2. For Each Activity to iterate on this list of files [image: For Each]
3. Copy Activity within the For Each Activity that will copy from Cosmos to Blob using the @item().name (to reference the FileName within the For Each), this allows you to use the FileName on the Source of your Copy Activity as well as specify @{item().name}-@{YourDateParameter} on the SINK of your Copy Activity. Doing this will use the name of the file picked up in the Get Metadata and append the Date to it when writing to Azure Blob Storage

Source of Copy Activity [image: Copy Source]

Sink of Copy Activity [image: Sink]
4. It actually working [image: Working]

Cheers